# List the results for particular class with all subjects

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, php-7.1

I am little fighting with a complexity, Any type help will be appreciable.
I have a database table including result of a class with subject name, max mark and mark obtained.. So now I want to list the results as follow:

```
roll no | English | Math  | Sceince | History | S.St.
1       | 50/100  |45/100 | 75/100  | 56/100  | 70/100
2       | 50/100  |45/100 | 75/100  | 56/100  | 70/100
```

and so on....
Now I am not able to find the solution that how will I show as everything is dynamic as rollno, subjects and max marks and mark obtains all are dynamic coming from database table..
So please help me once.

Comment: can you please show me a small piece of your source table

Comment: giving solution is difficult without seeing your table structure. please give me the table structure i will try to solve your issues.